# Creating forms with Zend Framework 2 – method attribute

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am creating a form with Zend Framework 2. Since I wasn't able to find a comprehensive documentation, I experimented a bit.

Usually, I set the `method` attribute for the form using `$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');`, either in the form or in the corresponding view.

Now I have noticed that when specifying no method attribute at all, the `method="POST"` attribute appears automatically in the opening form tag.

Where does this come from? Is it the default behavior of Zend Framework 2 or maybe the browser?

Comment: I've modified your question has I *believe* you got confused between `action` and `method`. You can revert if i'm incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The class [`Zend\Form\Form`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Form.php#L32) has the attribute already hard coded in the attributes array.

```
/**
 * Seed attributes
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $attributes = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
);
```

Interestingly the view helper used to render the form, `Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form`, [actually has `GET` as the default method value](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/Form.php#L84).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very interesting. So I probably should still declare `POST`, just to be safe?

Comment: No problem. I don't personally because you would need to specifically call `removeAttribute()` or `removeAttributes()` for it to be removed.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a small misunderstanding. I am just unsure if I  should set the `method` to `POST` using `setAttribute()`, although `Zend\Form\Form` does this by default? It may be minimal, but I don't want to clutter my code with unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html):

```
// Set the method attribute for the form
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
```

And default method for rendering Zend Form is GET, see Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form::openTag():

```
$attributes = array(
    'action' => '',
    'method' => 'get',
);
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said that *without* setting the method attribute they got `POST` (which means that `GET` can't be the default)